# Narrow down a whole metric to an instance in grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

If I have a prometheus metric as

```
((node_memory_MemTotal - node_memory_MemFree - node_memory_Buffers - node_memory_Cached) / node_memory_MemTotal) * 100
```

How can I apply that only to the current $instance ? I have tried surrounding it in brackets and adding:

```
{instance="$instance"}
```

(For which I have declared a variable), but it doesn't like it. Surely I don't have to repeat it after every metric name?

Answer (score 0):

> Surely I don't have to repeat it after every metric name?

Yes, for the best performance you should use the full selector with each metric:

```
((node_memory_MemTotal{instance="$instance"}
 - node_memory_MemFree{instance="$instance"}
 - node_memory_Buffers{instance="$instance"}
 - node_memory_Cached{instance="$instance"}
) / node_memory_MemTotal{instance="$instance"}
) * 100
```

Comment: If I do that, I get 'no data points'. Remove them and the data comes back. I've set it up the same way I have before with repeat for each value of instance...?